# Backbone boilerplate Events

Tags: backbone.js

What is the best way to bind events to a [Backbone boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) application? I've been trying to bind my events directly to the models associated with my views, in my views, but it doesn't seem to be working. I see within 'namespace.js', that there is an app key that extends Backbone.Events like so:

```
// Keep active application instances namespaced under an app object.
app: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
```

I don't fully understand how to use it...

I was able to get things working without the boilerplate, but it does provide some very cool functionality, so I'd love to be able to use it. Thanks!

ADDED

the code I was using was with the underscore bind method like so:

```
this.module.bind('change', this.render);
```

But then, I realized that 'this.model' is returning undefined, and so this doesn't work. I really am not sure how the boilerplate wants me to reference my model from the view.

Comment: Did you look through the backbonejs event docs? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: @abraham I have taken a look at the event docs. The makers of the boilerplate have extended the 'app' key within the namespace method which is attached to the DOMWindow, and globally available. Still I don't understand how that globally available object could keep track of specific changes to one of my model views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a typo that you copied from your code or a typo you only entered here, but I believe `this.module` (which IS undefined) *should* be `this.model`, which you also must be sure to pass in when you instantiate your view, of course, as so:

`myView = new BBView({model: myModel});`

then you can say `this.model.bind('change', this.render);` or `this.model.on('change', this.render);` for the most recent version of Backbone

I frequently bind my views to change events on my models in this way.

As for extending Backbone.Events, the way I have used it is to create an independent "event aggregator" that will help connect events between different views on your page. Let's say for example you have some action on one view that needs to set off an action on another view. In this case, you can pass your event aggregator object as an option to each of your views when you instantiate them, so that they can both trigger events or bind to events on a common object (i.e. your event aggregator).

`whatsUp = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events) // the aggregator`

`myFirstView = new FirstBBView ({whatsUp: whatsUp});`

(the aggregator shows up as `this.options.whatsUp` inside the view)

`mySecondView = new SecondBBView2 ({whatsUp: whatsUp});`

inside FirstBBView:

`this.options.whatsUp.bind('specialEvent', function(arg1,arg2) {
  // do stuff
});`

inside SecondBBView, when something important happens:

`this.options.whatsUp.trigger('specialEvent', {arg1: 'some data', arg2: 'more data'});`

For a great explanation, see [this great article by Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This was indeed the problem, and event aggregators is a nice little bonus! Nice resource.